# Storage, FireBase, Android - StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

Im trying to get the image from Firebase Storage and display it to the ImageView but i cant understand why i always get the error: "com.google.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location".
 I already tried everything but stills not working.

```
StorageReference storageRef;
StorageReference imageRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_op_details);

    imgPhoto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvPhoto1);

    txtView.setText(eventoOperacaoDB.getUsername());

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    imageRef = storageRef.child("97bce567-8f60-4637-a968-6734ba03cd35.png");


    imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            Picasso.with(opDetails.this).load(uri).into(imgPhoto1);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

            Toast.makeText(opDetails.this, ""+exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Images:

[Firebase Storage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtMH4.png)

[Firebase Storage Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqDRK.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting the same question again and again doesn't make any sense @NunoLeal. If you don't get the answer to that question plz have some patience or add bounty to the question.

Comment: Read the documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url